# How to remove the "Body :" word outputting from each search snippet in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to remove the "Body :" word outputting from each search snippet in drupal 7? 
I would be grateful for a turnkey solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the "Search results" display in the node type's Manage Display tab (go to node type's edit page). Also check the search-result.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Search Settings and find out what Display Mode is being used for your search results page.

Then go to the Structure > Content Types > [YOUR TYPE] > Manage Display > [DISPLAY USED BY SEARCH]

There should be a `Body` row in the list with an option in the middle that say `Label` and you can click `Hidden`, `Inline` or `Above`.